# Can't create test that extends WebTestCase in Symfony

Tags: symfony, phpunit, functional-testing, symfony5

I'm having difficulty creating functional test for my bundle. Whenever I create a test class that extends `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase` and launch `bin/phpunit`, I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot declare class <MyTestClass>, because the name is already in use in <path/to/my/test/class> on line <some_line>
```

I've got some unit tests running just fine. If I extend `PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase` for example, I get no problems launching my tests (but obviously I'm losing the functionality I need from WebTestCase).

My test class looks as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Some\Namespace\MyBundle\Test\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class UserControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        $client = self::createClient();
    }

    public function testCreateUser()
    {
    }
}
```

By the looks of it, it's the `self::createClient();` that causes the problem. However I do need the client to send some requests

Comment: Delete your cache directory and see if that helps.  This is one of those mysterious errors that seem to pop up from time to time.

Comment: I've tried it, didn't help unfortunately @Cerad

Comment: Do you actually have a class named "MyTestClass"?

Comment: Obviously the name's a little different, but yes, the class exists. Adding a class and extending WebTestCase in it triggers this error (that the class is already in use)